# How do I set the grayscale values for arrows in xypic?

Tags: color, xy-pic

I am trying to set the grayscale values of arrows in xypic. From a brief perusal [of this document](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xypic/xyrefer.pdf) it seems like I need to do something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newxycolor{testgray}{.5}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\xymatrix{\bullet \ar@[testgray][r] & \bullet}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

where the .5 is supposed to indicate something like halfway beetween black and white. But this just produces a black arrow,

[image]

and the error message "Current driver does not support colour." There is material about appropriate drivers in the linked document, but I don't understand it very well. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the color model. You find the syntax in section 13 of the Xy-pic reference guide (`texdoc xyrefer`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\newxycolor{testgray}{.5 gray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix{\bullet \ar@[testgray][r] & \bullet}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I added `cmtip` because my eyes bleed when I see the default arrow tips. Also `align` should never be used for simple equations not involving alignment (and `\xymatrix` alone doesn't count).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xcolor` package which provides the `gray` color.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{\bullet \ar@[gray][r] & \bullet}\]
\end{document}
```